# QApplication in threads

Tags: python, qt, asynchronous, spynner

I'm using a module named spynner with python. spynner runs on a QApplication instance. I need to run functions using spynner asynchronously.

I have tried calling these functions in different threads, using something like:
thread.start_new_thread(function_using_spynner)

This works if I run just one function, but if I try to run 2 of them I get an error saying that QApplication can not be created outside of main thread. Is there a way to run functions  asynchronously in the same thread? The functions return nothing, so just running them will be enough.

If not, is there a workaround for creating QApplication instances outside of main thread? I don't need a display.

Comment: By the way, you should use the [threading](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/threading) module rather than thread.

Answer (score 0):

You could run `function_using_spynner` in the main thread and do whatever else you need to do in the other thread. Alternatively, you could start the `QApplication` in spynner in the main thread before branching into multiple threads.

Comment: But in my case, I need to run three such functions simultaneously, so I need to run two of them in other threads. And about the latter, I've tried that, but that also causes several Qt specific problems, like: QObjest's parent must be in the same thread, can not create a child in another thread.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this using threads.  Maybe you could run several processes instead?

Comment: What will be the difference between running them in threads and processes?

Comment: @OzgurAkcali, Threads are essentially the same thing as processes EXCEPT they operate in the same memory space. Processes exist in their own memory space. Also, python threads don't take advantage of multicore processesors. Threads are lighter in terms of memory consumption though.